# How do I assign custom global variables from my config file?

Tags: config, variable, config-overrides

I'm currently developing custom config files.

Some of my files are deeply located in my architecture and I want to use some of my variables in the config as specific tag.

Example :

```
{site_url}assets/css/style.css
```

like that :

```
{css_url}style.css
```

Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
global $assign_to_config;
    if( ! isset($assign_to_config['global_vars']))
    {
        $assign_to_config['global_vars'] = array();
    }

    $main_global = array(
        'global:env'      => ENV,
        'global:env_full' => ENV_FULL
    );
$assign_to_config['global_vars'] = array_merge($assign_to_config['global_vars'], $master_global, $env_global);
```

Now I can assign custom global in my $main_global.

Answer (score 4):

You can still use the Global Variables Array, that formerly existed in the path.php file, but now exists in your primary index.php file for the site.

I've include an example of the formatting:

```
$assign_to_config['global_vars'] = array(
    'subsite_id' => 'subsite01',
    'subsite_no' => '259',
    'domain' => 'http://mydomain.org',
    'https' => $_SERVER["HTTPS"],
    ); // This array must be associative
```